# MySQL Query for Multiple Columns to be FILTERED?

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

Lets say i have 1 Table only with multiple columns. Lets say:

```
Fruits
--------------------------------------
id  | name        | country
--------------------------------------
1   | Banana      | china
2   | Orange      | japan
3   | Apple       | japan
4   | Apple       | china
5   | Banana      | usa
6   | Orange      | china
```

Then the simple query to `SELECT` all Fruits where `id < 6`.
It is:

```
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE id < 6
```

Then it will return:

```
--------------------------------------
id  | name        | country
--------------------------------------
1   | Banana      | china
2   | Orange      | japan
3   | Apple       | japan
4   | Apple       | china
5   | Banana      | usa
```

Then by appending above query, how can i go on to EXCLUDE something more.
For example:

```
Do NOT want to see, any "APPLE" from "CHINA".
```

So the final result must be:

```
--------------------------------------
id  | name        | country
--------------------------------------
1   | Banana      | china
2   | Orange      | japan
3   | Apple       | japan
5   | Banana      | usa
```

**This is again `without` the row that having `if, name='Apple' AND country='china'` TOGETHER!**.

- So by continuing the first query, how can i ADD the Additional "**AND Condition Pair**" to get this result, please?

I would say:

```
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE id < 6 ... AND DON'T RETURN this condition where name='Apple' and country='china' TOGETHER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE 
                 (name ,country) not in ( select 'Apple' ,'china' from Fruits)

 HAVING id < 6
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cc77/8)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM fruits 
WHERE (id < 6)
AND NOT (name = 'Apple' AND country = 'china')
```

Or:

```
SELECT * 
FROM fruits 
WHERE (id < 6)
AND id NOT IN (SELECT id 
               FROM fruits
               WHERE name = 'Apple'
               AND country = 'china')
```